# Cannot connect to SQL Server, error: 0 - No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL related matters so please bare with my lack of knowledge and asking a question which has been asked countless times before.

I have to connect to a SQL database server which is located at a remote location at xxx.xx.xxx.xx:3306, but every time I try to connect I get the same error:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)"

I get this same error whether I try to connect using SQL Server Management Studio or in a C# program via:

```
 SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(...)
 myConnection.Open();
```

I've tried it on two different computers, both on the same home network. I've had a look at the SQL server configuration manager on the computer which I installed SQL Server on, enabling TCP/IP and fiddling with the port values settings, but I'm guessing this is just for configuring an SQL server on my computer and irrelevant to connecting to a remote one. I shouldn't even need to install SQL server to do queries on a remote server anyway, right?

I've turned off my Windows firewall and my router firewall, though [ShieldsUP](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) still says

> Port: 3306 
>   Status: Stealth
>
> Your system has achieved a perfect "TruStealth" rating. Not a single packet — solicited or otherwise — was received from your system as a result of our security probing tests. Your system ignored and refused to reply to repeated Pings (ICMP Echo Requests). From the standpoint of the passing probes of any hacker, this machine does not exist on the Internet. Some questionable personal security systems expose their users by attempting to "counter-probe the prober", thus revealing themselves. But your system wisely remained silent in every way. Very nice.

I read that this is irrelevant as well, since I'm not the one hosting the server, but when I was given the address, I was given the port as well, so I must have to do something with it. I'm just not sure what. My understanding of ports really is quite shaky.

I've been trying this for over a day now, and I can't think of anything more I can do.

EDIT: I fixed the problem. I had to use MySQL, not MSSQL. Doh. Sorry guys.

Comment: In SSMS, did you enter the port as part of the server name?  In other words did you type:  xxx.xx.xxx.xx:3306 in the name of the server to connect to?

Comment: Where in SSMS should I enter that? I was under the impression that I wouldn't need to install SQL server just to query a remote database.

Comment: @DominicZedan who said you needed to install SQL Server?

Comment: FYI: "SSMS" means "SQL Server Management Studio".  Us old hands frquently forget that the acronym is not self-explanatory.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that as SSCM for some reason. Yeah, when I try entering xxx.xx.xxx.xx:3306 I get a "No such host is known" error. They gave me a code sample in python for the connection parameters, it's just:

MySQLdb.connect('xxx.xx.xxx.xx', 'username', 'pw', 'database');

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the remote SQL Server is running on port 3306 (otherwise I'm not sure why you talked in the question about that port specifically), try the following connection string:

```
user id=username; password=password;
data source=123.45.678.90,3306; 
initial catalog=dbname; 
Network Library=dbmssocn;
```

I think without the port you'll have trouble if the other end has disabled the SQL Browser service. You should also make sure it isn't a named instance, in which case you may need:

```
user id=username; password=password;
data source=123.45.678.90\InstaneName,3306; 
initial catalog=dbname; 
Network Library=dbmssocn;
```

Comment: I think that the Instance Name is a No-Op if you specify a port number. (At least that's been my experience).

Comment: @RBarryYoung I think you're right, but I don't recall the last time I dealt with a fixed port named instance when the browser service was disabled.

Comment: Putting 123.45.678.90,3306 gives me a "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" error. I've been told not to use an instance name. I think I'll contact the server host.

Comment: Where are you putting that `IP,port` that gives you an "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" error? That doesn't sound right at all. Perhaps you could show the code that is causing that error, but please do find out the correct details from the server host (like what is the IP, what is the port number for SQL Server, and is the firewall open for you) first.

Comment: SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=username;" +
                                       "password=pw;server=xxx.xx.xxx.xx,3306;" +
                                       "database=db; " +
                                       "connection timeout=3; Network Library=dbmssocn;");

I get the same error in C# and SMSS (entering xxx.xx.xxx.xx,3306 into the server name field).

Answer (score 0):

First of all the database is local or distant ?
The you have to ensure that your connection string is well written.
Here's an example of a valid connection string :

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

More about connection strings :
[Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Now if everything is set up correctly you have to enable remote connections to SQL Server on the host. To do so please refer to this article :
[Enable SQL Server Remote Connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

Comment: The database is distant (in another country). It's a company's test database that other people are working on so presumably it's set up correctly, but if I don't get anywhere soon I'll send them an email. My connection string is 

user id=username; password=password;server=123.45.678.90;                                     database=dbname; connection timeout=3; Network Library=dbmssocn;

Comment: And I'm sure it should be just xxx.xx.xxx.xx and not xxx.xx.xxx.xx:3306, the latter gives me a "No such host is known" error.

Comment: It shouldn't be a colon, it should be a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to ypur serveices and check whether your **SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)** is running.Most of the time this error happens when SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) is stopped.
[image]

Then select it right click and click start.problem solved !!!